# Potential virus as Excel macro, opened on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ms-office, virus

I have just received and email which contained an Excel file with a potential virus in form of macro. I opened the attachment on my iPhone (because it looked like an invoice I was actually expecting) but nothing happened and it looked empty. Then I downloaded it to my Mac and opened the file *but* I chose the options to run *without* macros enabled. The Excel was empty, so I closed it and deleted the file. then I was thinking that it was some kind of virus/malware.

I guess with my Mac, I am safe with just opening with macros disabled but what about my iPhone? Do macros work on iPhone? Does this pose a risk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros do not run on iOS. iOS opens such files using Preview, which renders entirely differently to an actual copy of Excel. Furthermore, even if you open the file in the Excel app on iOS, macros are still unavailable.